# drupal-media ckeditor tag not well rendered for remote and local video

Tags: media

i'm running a 9.3.16 drupal site with media and media_library modules enabled. I've three types of media entities : video, remote video and image. I can upload and display the three types of media on their detail page. The videos players are good.

I've configured text format of ckeditor to show media_library button. And added text filters. The video are displayed in ckeditor of the body field.

But when I display the content type the video player is not showing. But the other fields of video media type yes.

The template is {{ content.body.0 }}

No dblog message.

Could you enlight me a little?

Comment: Does it work when you render the entire variable {{ content }}?

Comment: Is the field in the display settings, is it set to the right formatter, etc.

Comment: Formatters are good. I've also configured Gutenberg for the body field. Many embed gutenberg blocks are fine. But youtube embed et video of media library are not.